# iPhone "from messages" paste to text box not triggering capturable events

Tags: jquery, iphone

I have a web application that requests an OTP through sms and the input for that OTP is 6 individual boxes.  The iPhone provides a feature that allows simply clicking the "from messages" quick link after receiving the text message to populate the data in a normal text box.  However since I have 6 individual text boxes each limited to maxlength=1, only the first digit of the OTP is provided to the first box.

I have written code that will correctly take the paste command from the user input and parse it to place in the 6 individual boxes, but it does not work when doing the quick action.  I have tried capturing "change", "paste", "keyup" and "keypress" events and I am not able to detect that the "from messages" has occurred to do anything with it.

Other than switching to a single text box, is there anything I can do to correctly populate those boxes.  I will admit that I am not familiar with the browser capabilities of the iPhone.

Comment: welcome to SO. please include your codes along with your question. You can also use [codepen](https://codepen.io/) or a similar tool to share your code.

Comment: Have you tried `input` event?